# Prove that $e^{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}\geq\frac{1}{2024}\sqrt[2024]{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\dots(x_n+1)}\big(2023x_1+2023x_2+\dots+2023x_n+2024\big)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

Let $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in\Bbb R_{\geq -1}$ . Prove that the inequality

$$
\begin{aligned}e^{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}\geq\frac{1}{2024}\sqrt[2024]{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\dots(x_n+1)}\big(2023x_1+2023x_2+\dots+2023x_n+2024\big)
\end{aligned}
$$

---

holds.

The above inequality was shared by a mathematics book author for high school students in my location.  I wanted to share this inequality here.  Although it is stated that solution techniques only require high school knowledge, all the techniques applied here will add color to the solutions.

I noticed that the equality occurs if and only if $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=0$ .

First I tried to get the $2024$th power of each side.  But the calculations made the inequality more complicated.

The inequality $e^x\geq x+1$ gives $e^{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n}=x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n+1$. So it is sufficient to prove $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n+1\geq\frac{1}{2024}\sqrt[2024]{(x_1+1)(x_2+1)\dots(x_n+1)}\big(2023x_1+2023x_2+\dots+2023x_n+2024\big)$. But I think this procedure seems not easy.

I will edit the question in a few hours and add my own progress here and if a solution comes along, I will gladly share it with you here.

Thanks in advance for your interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the inequality $e^{rx}\geq 1+ rx$ for $x > -1$ we have:
$$
\exp\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i + \frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}\right)^{1/2024}\exp\left(\frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\geq \left(\prod_{i=1}^n 1+x_i\right)^{1/2024} \exp\left(\frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \geq \left(\prod_{i=1}^n 1+x_i\right)^{1/2024} \left(1+\frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right),
$$
and done!

Comment: But, if $1+\frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i<0$, does your inequality work ?

Comment: @hardmath We can assume that $1 + \frac{2023}{2024}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq 0$, since otherwise the original inequality holds trivially.

Comment: I can not get why we can assume ?

Comment: @hardmath I've updated the answer, I've realized that it's easier to just switch the order of inequalities, then you don't have to worry about edge cases :)